# Drupal 8. How to clear cache at 12 am? Or another specific hour

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-cache

Drupal 8. How to clear cache at 12 am? Or another specific hour, for example 2pm, 7pm etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it outside of Drupal, using a cron job on your server to call `drush cr` for your site.

In case you are not familiar with cron, please refer here: https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux

#### Example:

1. Edit crontab:

`crontab -e`

2. Add following line:

`0 0 * * * cd <path_to_your_document_root> && drush cr`

Answer (score 2):

Check out also on CacheFlush module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheflush/